# Windows Permissions - can I assign file access rights to a Program (not Users)

Tags: windows, file, permissions

Not sure if possible, but this the scenario:

A 'background' process writes to a log for its 'own' use. The same file is 'shared' across ALL users.

QUESTION: 
Can I assign read/write/delete etc rights to a specific PROGRAM as opposed to a USER (currently forced to set to all). Although file itself is 'hidden', it would be preferable that no one could fiddle with it, including directories etc. Can Windows make such a distinction, and if so how?

Answer (score 2):

the unix way of dealing with such a problem, is to create a special user (named after the program or service in question), and set the file access rights of the file to this specific user.

Comment: That is correct. On Windows (as on *nix) a program is not a trustee and cannot "own" objects, nor be part of an ACL. Create an unprivileged user on the system and let your program run as this user.